# Why does unpacking the contents of the same zipped file differ in their byte arrays?

Tags: java, unzip, zip

We have zip archives on our server that contain `.csv` files. If requested, we want to deliver those files as `.xlsx` within a newly created archive. I have already written the code to do the conversion using `apache-poi` and am having trouble asserting the results during testing.

In my test, I have one input zip file that contains a `.csv`. I run the test once and store the result of the conversion as a zip file (to use it as the expected output afterwards). I understand that comparing the resulting zip archives directly is not possible, so I unpack them, read all bytes of each file in both folders and compare them with `Assertions.assertArrayEquals`. This is where I run into trouble. Here and there, the arrays are off in both length and content.

Can anyone tell me why that is? When I look at the actual files, they are the same and how they should look like after conversion.

Comment: It's conceivable that this is down to character encoding. Adopt a standard such as UTF-8 and make sure you stick to it. I can't be more precise as I don't know how your pure text is being done

Comment: xlsx files are, in actual fact, zip files. unzip the xlsx files as well and compare their contents, like you do with the zip files. you may find the reason for the difference. Another thought: do the xlsx files open in Excel after you open them? If that doesn't help, post you comparison code - you may not be asserting the zip file contents correctly. See [mcve]